# How to remove Query from JFrame GUI in Netebeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have accidentally dragged "Query" from Java Persistence Section in Windows Palette.

Now I have hard time removing it from the source code. Below is a screen shot.

[image]

How can I restore my interface?

Comment: `hard time removing it from the source code` Hard time how? Can't you just delete it from the source code?

Comment: I tried right clicking on "query1:Query" and nothing came up that would allow me to delete it. If I go to Source code notice how it is grayed out and even there it does not allow me to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Open the GUI-Editor again and remove it from there (see Window/Panel: Navigator).
Or open the file in any text-editor to remove it.
(Don't forget to re-load the form within NetBeans-GUI-Designer after changing code via Text-Editor)